# Show different content for each enlarged tile using isotope

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using the isotope control to zoom into a card and relayout the collection. I would also like to show different content when each tile is enlarged - each enlarged tile would show a different graphic/content. The current example I use only associates a class(large) with the tile, but I want it to show different content as well. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DsnNX/

```
  $(function(){
  var $container = $('#container'),
  $items = $('.item');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    layoutMode : 'fitColumns',
    resizesContainer : false,
    getSortData : {
      fitOrder : function( $item ) {
        var order,
            index = $item.index();

        if ( $item.hasClass('large') && index % 2 ) {
          order = index + 1.5;
        } else {
          order = index;
        }
        return order;
      }
    },
    sortBy : 'fitOrder'
  });

  $items.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // nothing to change if this already has large class
    if ( $this.hasClass('large') ) {
      return;
    }
    var $previousLargeItem = $items.filter('.large');

    $previousLargeItem.removeClass('large');
    $this.addClass('large');
    $container
      // update sort data on changed items
      .isotope('updateSortData', $this )
      .isotope('updateSortData', $previousLargeItem )
      // trigger layout and sort
      .isotope();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can put HTML content inside of isotope tiles with no difficulty, why not simply have the content there all the time inside of the `.item` elements with `display: none` and then show them when the `.large` (active/clicked) class is present?

**[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DsnNX/2/)** demonstrating a very VERY simple implementation of this.

Essentially I just wrapped the numbers in `span` tags so they can be targeted with CSS and added a hidden content div in each block whose display is toggled based on the parent `.item` element having the `.large` class.

There is also an `onLayout` option for isotope that allows you to specify a function that is called each time the layout/relayout is triggered (e.g. any time an element is selected in your case) kind of like a callback - you could also use this to manage changing content on the active element, or even just update the content dynamically via the JS `click` event handler function you already have in your example.